# App won't open specific web page?

Tags: windows-phone-8, mobile-website

I'm developing a Windows Phone 8 application that's basically a wrapper for a mobile website. The only issue being that the app will not open the webpage. I can open any other website (google, yahoo, etc...) but whenever i try to open the mobile site, it won't render anything. I can even have two webviews loaded, one the mobile site and one yahoo, and the yahoo one will load and the other won't. I'm thinking it could be the server settings, but i don't know if there's a way around that or not. Does anybody know what i should do? or has anybody had this problem before?

Comment: There could be multiple issues, but there are two things that will help us narrow it down. 1. Multiple browser controls on a page are not supported. Can you confirm that this occurs if there's only one being used. 2. What's the site/URI that you're trying to load? Without this you're leaving us to guess at what the issue may be.

Comment: It won't work with either one or multiple browser controls. I can tell it to load one page and it'll just stop, then i close the test, set the page to open google or any other page and it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript in a `WebBrowser` is disabled by default. Does it work when you change the `IsScriptEnabled` value to `true`?

```
<phone:WebBrowser IsScriptEnabled="True" Name="WebBrowserView" />
```